# Bluetooth Trasmitter

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I am building an app that is supposed to detect a bluetooth signal from a device.  I have been looking at a lot of blueotooth 4.0 boards but I am clueless as to what I need or what other components I am supposed to get with the board.

All I want is for the device to broadcast a bluetooth signal with a unique ID.  Nothing else.  This signal will then be picked up by the app on the phone.

What kind of component do I need to achieve this? What is the cheapest most dependable solution for broadcasting the signal?

Answer (score 2):

A basic way of doing this is to go the Arduino route. You can purchase bluetooth modules that are compatible with the serial lines of an Arduino. The bluetooth module will already have its own ID and to transmit data all you need to do is send serial to the bluetooth module from the Arduino board.

This is a simple method that will be very easy to implement. All the components you need are an Arduino, (an Arduino Uno would suffice) and a bluetooth 4.0 Arduino compatible module.

Comment: The device itself will not transmit any data, just need it to broadcast the signal alone with the bluetooth id.

Comment: The bluetooth protocol has a set method of sending data, I don't think that will allow for just sending the ID. There is the bluetooth advertising packet, but i'm not sure if that suits your needs.

Comment: Bluetooth modules are detectable when they are powered, because they send out advertising packets. Maybe that is all you need?

Comment: Yes that is all I need :)